# PHP remove trailing 0's from time

Tags: php, string, datetime, time

If I have a datetime like:

`24/10/2019 21:00`

1. If the time is 21:01 or anything other than 0, I'm fine with the minutes appearing.
2. If the time ends 00 then I'd like the colon and 0's removed.

Is there a php date function to do this, or do I need to do some php preg_replace or something?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `str_replace` if you datetime string has no seconds.

```
str_replace(":00","","24/10/2019 21:00");
```

---

While if your datetime may has seconds, you can do it with,

```
$datetime = "24/10/2019 21:00";
while(substr($datetime,-3) == ':00'){
    $datetime = substr($datetime,0, strlen($datetime) - 3);
}
echo $datetime;
```

Comment: I think your answer is correct, but you can also use `preg_replace` like in @Don't Panic's answer for a simpler version of your second solution.

Comment: Simple string operation is more efficient than regular operation here.

Answer (score 2):

There isn't a function to automatically do this as far as I know. You can convert the string

```
$dateString = '24/10/2019 21:00';
```

to a timestamp or a DateTime object, then format it conditionally based on the number of minutes.

```
// Timestamp    
$timestamp = strtotime(str_replace('/', '-', $dateString));
$newDateString = date('d/m/Y H' . ($timestamp % 3600 ? ':i' : ''), $timestamp);

// Or DateTime object
$dateTime = date_create_from_format('d/m/Y H:i', $dateString);
$newDateString = $dateTime->format('d/m/Y H' . ($dateTime->format('i') == 0 ? '' : ':i'));
```

But that seems unnecessarily complex when you can just remove a trailing ":00".

```
$newDateString = preg_replace('/:00$/', '', $dateString);
```

Be sure to include the `$` in the pattern to only match the `:00` at the end of the string.

Comment: Ahh beat me to it. Missed the `$` to end that string

Comment: @MiroslavGlamuzina Sorry, it can be frustrating when that happens. I wish there was a way to see if someone else was writing an answer. I thought about just leaving it as a comment, but I wanted to show the relative complexity of some different ways to do it.

Comment: It's all good, it happens, plus yours was much more thorough. It would also be nice if at least we got a notification if the question has been closed :D.

Comment: Given that there is no seconds part in the input, a simple `str_replace(':00','',$dateString)` will suffice. No need for `preg_replace`.

Comment: @Nick oh yeah! So obvious now that you mention it. I thought I was simplifying it, ha

Comment: Useful to know all the same @Don'tPanic, sometimes there might be a seconds part.  Thanks for the answer.